# Lookup table based on input image color in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, lookup-tables

Suppose I have two input images. One only contains three colors such as green, red, and blue as labels. Another image that needs to be edited based on the colors in the first image. So, for instance, wherever the label image is red, I'd like function `A` to happen on the original image.

To do this, I would like to create a lookup that gets a color as input and outputs a function to be executed on the original image.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) for this.

```
im1 = [0 0 1; 
       1 2 0; 
       2 2 1];
im2 = rand(3);
```

find where `im1` equals `1`:

```
idx = im1 == 1;
```

`idx` is now a matrix of logicals which can act as a mask for `im2`:

```
idx = 

    0   0   1
    1   0   0
    0   0   1
```

do something to all the corresponding pixels of `im2`:

```
im2(idx) = im2(idx) + 5;
```

Also, although I doubt this is what you were asking, you could define your function `A` using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
A = @(x)(2.*x.^2 - x + 5)
im2(idx) = A(im2(idx))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to dig into this a bit more although I was mainly asking about creating a lookup table for this since in the actual code I will have a lot more color labels than just 3. Also, when dealing with color labels, is it always better to convert the input label image to index from rgb? (I get some artifacts on label borders when I do this by rgb2ind with no dithering!)

Comment: Dan, quick question. If I want to find a range of values in the image that are not exactly for example 0.9, how can I do that? I tried `idx = im2(:,:,1) == (abs(im2(:,:,1) - 0.9)<=epsilon)` but it's not really working as expected Just a some of the pixels are retrieved. Thoughts?

Comment: Actually got it working. Instead of == had to put <=

Comment: Dan, I have a question. When I do something like `im2(idx) = im2(idx) + 5;` it seems to only add 5 to the red channel! Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks

Comment: You said your colours were labels, so I assumed it was not an RGB image. If you have the correct index for your RGB image (and it is slightly different to get) then to apply the mask to all the channels you would need to get row and column indexes separately (e.g. `[ri, ci] = find(...)`) and then to apply it `im2(ri,ci,:) + 5`. But it's a different question to what you've asked.